# Get/capture all variableNames and values from JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, php, regex, interpreter

So, I have a large .js file and I want to get all variables defined in it, with values. I want to do this from PHP (if it was JS, it would be easy).

So, for example, I have this code:

```
var var1="var value";
var var2={
    something:'value'
};
window.var3 = 80+100
;var4='another var value';
```

I should get a list like this:

1. variable "var1" with value: "var value"
2. variable "var2" with value: {something:'value'}
3. variable "var3" with value: 80+100
4. variable "var4" with value: 'another var value'

I was trying to do this using regex, but I can't find a regex that guarantees to capture everything.

Here are some issues I encountered:

1. line can be terminated without ;
2. actual value can contain ;
3. there may not be a value (e.g. `var variable1;`)

Here is the regex I made:

```
/(?:var[\s]+|window\.){0,1}([^;\s]*)(?:\s*)=(?:\s*)([^;]*)(?:\s*);{0,1}/i
```

Does anyone have a different approach? Or a better regex?

I was also thinking about using a PHP lib that interprets JS: [J4P5](http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/) or [V8js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php)

Thanks

Comment: Extracting variables and their values from a js script with regex is near from impossible, there's too many traps: comments, strings, literal regexes *(this one is the most difficult to deal with)*, nested parenthesis. You can't do that without a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really be sure you capture all the variable content you definitely will need to use a JS parser, run the code and then output the full variable context from the parser. In the end you could also have stuff like this:

```
var whatever = (function() { return 4; })();
```

This is perfectly valid javascript, could happen and is normally more complex than just a return then.

Running the code however does have some safety issues if this is user provided code as someone could for example include calls to external resources into the code easily then. So extra care is needed here.

Comment: I decided to go with a temporary regex solution. It already does not work 100%, but enough for my needs. Will have to switch to a parser in the future